# stop htaccess from ignoring

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdirectory

I'm having a nightmare with my htaccess file... i have a parked domain name that i want to redirect EVERYTHING to a subfolder inside the public_html
so i used this code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?parked\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1 [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

Its working perfect now it redirects     `www.parked.com`  *=it shows >*   `public_html/foo` content but inside the **public_html** folder i also have a folder called admin and inside folder **foo** i also have a folder called admin

- public_html/admin
- public_html/foo
- public_html/foo/admin

the problem is that every time i try to access **`www.parked.com/admin`** it shows the **`public_html/admin`** folder not **`public_html/admin`**

what i want it to do is to completely redirect **www.parked.com** to `public_html/foo` and ignores the file inside **`public_html`**

Comment: Can you put rewrite log here?

Answer (score 0):

Why did you put conditions to the end of rules? That should work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?parked\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```